# DFS for 10x10 grid

Tags: java, depth-first-search

So I have a 10x10 grid which contains an enemy and the player, originally positioned at (0,0). The enemy needs to search for the player using dfs. The goal state will be constantly changing as the player will move and then the enemy will follow suit. I'm having problems with some of the tutorials that explain about directed trees and such. This is not suitable for this as the enemy may need to go back to a previously 'visited' square. Also a lot of the tutorials talk about adding connections explicitly in the code. This would be crazy with 100 potential positions?

I'm not looking for a code solution or anything like that, just a clear path to follow would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: 1) Why do you need to do this with DFS? Not sure that's feasible if the player is moving while the enemy is searching. 2) Can the enemy sense the location, direction or distance of the player?

Comment: 2) The enemy knows the players position on the grid. The enemy may be at (7,6) and the player at (0,0). 1)I don't to be honest. I can implement any search algorithm. Currently im implementing my own where the enemy tries to match the players x coordinates first and then their y coordinates. However this is a school project and so having added value by implementing an actual recognized search algorithm rather than my own is desired. However a more simple algorithm would be possible

Comment: If the enemy knows the player's position, then it doesn't have to search for it. If you had obstacles in the grid, you'd need to search for a path to the known position. Otherwise, the enemy can just move progressively closer and closer. BTW, if diagonal moves aren't supported, you might consider alternating horizontal and vertical moves while both deltas are nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Look into linked nodes.  Each one will have 4 node references in it (some of which will be null on the edges of your board), and maybe containsEnemy and containsPlayer booleans.

Comment: This seems more of an implementation detail than an answer to this question.